# Is it possible to save the result of a DB query to be doled out over multiple HTTPRequests?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to think up a way to execute a MySQL query, get 50 rows back, inform the requester that it has 50 rows to get, and then send 10 rows.  But the server can't say "Take this next set of data" (can it?).  But it can say "there is more data" and the user can send ANOTHER request.  But I dont' want another SQL query to be performed, I just want the results of the first query to be cahced somewhere and then the user knows where it is adn says "I need the next 10 entries from memory @ ***_*_**"

The end goal is I want to be able to have an iPhone app that can request large amounts of information but only ever be waiting for ONE of those pieces.  This way the user can interact with what has been returned thus far instead of waiting 30 seconds and then finally being able to do things.

Comment: Some unlucky users will still be waiting 30 seconds whenever the cache entry expires or the data requested is not within the set saved in the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the query results in [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). That way you don't have to do multiple sql requests.

Comment: +1 Agree. But think first if it's worth the effort. For a trivial query you usually don't need it.